# Use Apple Pencil through Qt framework

Tags: c++, ios, qt, objective-c++

I want to port my Qt application to use the apple pencil on an iPad Pro. Currently, my app uses [QTabletEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabletevent.html) to draw to a [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) using a Wacom enabled device. I'm planning on trying to handle events from apple pencil with objective-c++ and feed it into Qt's event system. I've never used objective-c++, what are some good tutorials to try to solve this problem? I'm specifically looking for how to pass events from objective-c++ to Qt.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any Qt code from methods in Objective C++ code. You can easily create new events and post them to your application.